# Call globally used sql connection in app.config for insert query?

Tags: c#, sql, c#-4.0, app-config, windows

I have set the path for sql server in app.config and I want to insert data in the table?

1. how will I call that connection string?
2. I want to set this connection as the global connection for my project how will I call it on my each page in the project?

Answer (score 0):

```
using (SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YourConfigFileAssignName"].ConnectionString))
{

};
```

`YourConfigFileAssignName` is the assigned name of sour connection string in the `app.config` file.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="YourConfigFileAssignName" 
         connectionString="Data Source=YourDataSource;Initial Catalog=YourDBname;User ID=SQLid;Password=SQLpass" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Tnk u so much sir